How to show seconds of last modified date when using sftp command?
When I use WinSCP to access my SFTP server, it shows me the last modified (changed) date including seconds. If I use sftp on Linux and run ls -l, it only shows the hours and minutes, but no seconds. How can I also show the seconds using sftp, like WinSCP does it?
I already checked the sftp man page and the ls options there, but could not find a  matching option.

You can always switch to a different SFTP client that supports it.
For instance, with lftp (which supports a large number of file transfer protocols including SFTP), you can use its cls command which does the formatting client-side and has a --time-style option à la GNU ls:
lftp chazelas@localhost:/usr> cls --time-style=+%FT%T%z -l
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        60478 2024-12-17T06:12:02+0000 bin/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            0 2024-11-03T13:06:44+0000 games/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         4166 2024-12-15T13:01:36+0000 include/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         2636 2024-12-11T19:47:15+0000 lib/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         1626 2024-12-06T07:54:35+0000 lib32/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           40 2024-12-06T07:54:40+0000 lib64/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         6312 2024-12-17T06:12:15+0000 libexec/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         1728 2024-12-06T07:54:38+0000 libx32/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           72 2021-06-27T07:13:26+0100 local/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        12014 2024-12-17T06:12:15+0000 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         6646 2024-12-13T12:56:11+0000 share/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            0 2024-11-03T13:14:31+0000 src/

lftp chazelas@localhost:/usr> cls --time-style=full-iso  -l
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        60478 2024-12-17 06:12:02 bin/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            0 2024-11-03 13:06:44 games/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         4166 2024-12-15 13:01:36 include/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         2636 2024-12-11 19:47:15 lib/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         1626 2024-12-06 07:54:35 lib32/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           40 2024-12-06 07:54:40 lib64/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         6312 2024-12-17 06:12:15 libexec/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         1728 2024-12-06 07:54:38 libx32/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           72 2021-06-27 07:13:26 local/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        12014 2024-12-17 06:12:15 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         6646 2024-12-13 12:56:11 share/
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            0 2024-11-03 13:14:31 src/

Like the sftp that comes with openssh, it looks like it doesn't support displaying the access time, change time, birth time or subsecond part of the modification time even though, looking at the code it does have support for retrieving those over the protocol.
yafc (FTP and SFTP client) has a filetime command which gives the last modification time with second precision:
yafc chazelas@localhost:/usr> filetime src
src: Sun Nov  3 13:14:31 2024

Or you can use the Net::SFTP::Foreign perl module:
$ perl -MPOSIX -MNet::SFTP::Foreign -le '
  $s = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("localhost");
  print strftime("%FT%T%z ", localtime $_->{a}->mtime) . $_->{filename}
    for @{$s->ls("/usr")}'
2021-06-27T07:13:26+0100 .
2024-12-03T08:22:33+0000 ..
2024-12-17T06:12:02+0000 bin
2024-12-17T06:12:15+0000 sbin
2024-12-11T19:47:15+0000 lib
2024-12-06T07:54:35+0000 lib32
2024-12-06T07:54:40+0000 lib64
2024-12-06T07:54:38+0000 libx32
2024-12-13T12:56:11+0000 share
2024-11-03T13:06:44+0000 games
2024-12-15T13:01:36+0000 include
2024-11-03T13:14:31+0000 src
2024-12-17T06:12:15+0000 libexec
2021-06-27T07:13:26+0100 local

(only mtime and atime (not Btime, ctime) and no subsecond precision)
Another option is to use sshfs (which uses the SFTP protocol underneath) to mount the remote FS locally, then you can use local commands to display those timestamps. However, testing here on Debian trixie it doesn't look like subsecond precision nor birth time are supported:
$ sshfs localhost:/usr mnt
$ ls --full-time mnt
total 116
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60478 2024-12-17 06:12:02.000000000 +0000 bin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 2024-11-03 13:06:44.000000000 +0000 games/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4166 2024-12-15 13:01:36.000000000 +0000 include/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2636 2024-12-11 19:47:15.000000000 +0000 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1626 2024-12-06 07:54:35.000000000 +0000 lib32/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    40 2024-12-06 07:54:40.000000000 +0000 lib64/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6312 2024-12-17 06:12:15.000000000 +0000 libexec/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1728 2024-12-06 07:54:38.000000000 +0000 libx32/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    72 2021-06-27 07:13:26.000000000 +0100 local/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12014 2024-12-17 06:12:15.000000000 +0000 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6646 2024-12-13 12:56:11.000000000 +0000 share/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0 2024-11-03 13:14:31.000000000 +0000 src/

$ ls --time=birth -l mnt
total 116
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60478            ? bin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0            ? games/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4166            ? include/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2636            ? lib/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1626            ? lib32/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    40            ? lib64/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6312            ? libexec/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1728            ? libx32/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    72            ? local/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12014            ? sbin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6646            ? share/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     0            ? src/

Or Gnome I/O (as you'd use in nautilus, Gnome's default file manager for instance) and its gio CLI interface:
$ gio mount sftp://localhost/usr
$ gio list -a time sftp://localhost/usr
bin     60486   (directory)     time::modified=1734422749 time::access=1734422773
sbin    12014   (directory)     time::modified=1734415935 time::access=1734415955
lib     2636    (directory)     time::modified=1733946435 time::access=1734415801
lib32   1626    (directory)     time::modified=1733471675 time::access=1734415801
lib64   40      (directory)     time::modified=1733471680 time::access=1734036576
libx32  1728    (directory)     time::modified=1733471678 time::access=1734415801
share   6646    (directory)     time::modified=1734094571 time::access=1734277015
games   0       (directory)     time::modified=1730639204 time::access=1732375138
include 4166    (directory)     time::modified=1734267696 time::access=1734330298
src     0       (directory)     time::modified=1730639671 time::access=1732479037
libexec 6312    (directory)     time::modified=1734415935 time::access=1734415955
local   72      (directory)     time::modified=1624774406 time::access=1732384794

$ gio info sftp://localhost/usr/src
display name: src
edit name: src
name: src
type: directory
size:  0
uri: sftp://localhost/usr/src
local path: /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=localhost/usr/src
unix mount: gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000
attributes:
  standard::type: 2
  standard::is-symlink: FALSE
  standard::name: src
  standard::display-name: src
  standard::edit-name: src
  standard::icon: inode-directory, folder, inode-directory-symbolic, folder-symbolic
  standard::content-type: inode/directory
  standard::fast-content-type: inode/directory
  standard::size: 0
  standard::symbolic-icon: inode-directory-symbolic, folder-symbolic, inode-directory, folder
  etag::value: 1730639671
  id::filesystem: sftp:host=localhost
  access::can-read: TRUE
  access::can-execute: TRUE
  access::can-trash: FALSE
  time::modified: 1730639671
  time::access: 1732479037
  unix::mode: 16877
  unix::uid: 0
  unix::gid: 0

$ ls -l --full-time /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=localhost/usr
total 97
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas 60486 2024-12-17 08:05:49.000000000 +0000 bin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas     0 2024-11-03 13:06:44.000000000 +0000 games/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas  4166 2024-12-15 13:01:36.000000000 +0000 include/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas  2636 2024-12-11 19:47:15.000000000 +0000 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas  1626 2024-12-06 07:54:35.000000000 +0000 lib32/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas    40 2024-12-06 07:54:40.000000000 +0000 lib64/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas  6312 2024-12-17 06:12:15.000000000 +0000 libexec/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas  1728 2024-12-06 07:54:38.000000000 +0000 libx32/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas    72 2021-06-27 07:13:26.000000000 +0100 local/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas 12014 2024-12-17 06:12:15.000000000 +0000 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas  6646 2024-12-13 12:56:11.000000000 +0000 share/
drwxr-xr-x 1 chazelas chazelas     0 2024-11-03 13:14:31.000000000 +0000 src/

The KIO KDE equivalent:
$ kioclient stat sftp://localhost/usr/src
NAME                  src
SIZE                  0
FILE_TYPE             0040000
USER                  0
GROUP                 0
ACCESS                0755
MODIFICATION_TIME     Sun Nov 3 13:14:31 2024
ACCESS_TIME           Sun Nov 24 20:10:37 2024


nice, today I learned there's a free-standing gio utility. Handy!

It seems the sftp client doesn't do that.
So, I'm afraid your only option is to either use regular ssh server_name ls -l /path/to/file to read these properties, or use the (maybe elegant?) ability of Linux to have userland file systems, and use sshfs server:/path/to localdirectory/ && ls -l --time-style=long-iso localdirectory.

However he wants to see seconds, and mere ls -l will not show show them...

@Arfrever well, true. Add --time-style=long-iso (or follow your example)!

According to Man page of sftp, it is not possible to display the full time of file.
# man sftp

ls [-1afhlnrSt] [path]
               Display a remote directory listing of either path or the
               current directory if path is not specified.  path may
               contain glob(7) characters and may match multiple files.

               The following flags are recognized and alter the
               behaviour of ls accordingly:

               -1      Produce single columnar output.

               -a      List files beginning with a dot (‘.’).

               -f      Do not sort the listing.  The default sort order
                       is lexicographical.

               -h      When used with a long format option, use unit
                       suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte,
                       Terabyte, Petabyte, and Exabyte in order to
                       reduce the number of digits to four or fewer
                       using powers of 2 for sizes (K=1024, M=1048576,
                       etc.).

               -l      Display additional details including permissions
                       and ownership information.

               -n      Produce a long listing with user and group
                       information presented numerically.

               -r      Reverse the sort order of the listing.

               -S      Sort the listing by file size.

               -t      Sort the listing by last modification time.

https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#ls
